# How to convert LocalDateTime to LocalDate in JPA Query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have object with field `LocalDateTime dateTime`. And I have the following repository method

```
@Query("select m from MyClass m " +
                "where m.dateTime >= :startDate and m.dateTime <= :endDate")
findAllByTradeTimeBetween(@Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate, 
                          @Param("endDate") LocalDate endDate);
```

How to get `LocalDate` of `LocalDateTime dateTime` in this method . Now I have an exception

```
Parameter value [2020-01-31] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: So you want `Date` or `LocalDate`?

Comment: i need LocalDate

Comment: @deHaar he meant in the other direction

Comment: @Andronicus Oh, yes... just realized ;-) Thanks for pointing...

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can format it in the query (SQL), but that seems not the best idea, even if possible... See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691543/how-to-use-date-format-when-using-jpql-jpa), you may end up losing database independency.

Comment: Simillar ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352754/sql-error-1064-sqlstate-42000-in-query-jpa-mysql-hibernate/63353263#63353263

Answer (score 2):

It would seem more strict to keep the query in LocalDateTime, and add an API for LocalDate versions.

```
@Query("select m from MyClass m " +
                "where m.dateTime >= :startDate and m.dateTime < :endDate")
findAllByTradeTimeBetween(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate, 
                          @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);

findAllByTradeTimeBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    return findAllByTradeTimeBetween(startDate.atStartOfDay(),
                                     endDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay());
}
```

This opens the API for some dubious usage (using LocalDateTimes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an javax.persistence.AttributeConverter to automate the conversion between the Date formats. Here's the Converter class which will automatically convert the LocalDateTime object to LocalDate and viceversa:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, LocalDate> {
        @Override
        public LocalDate convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
            //convert localDateTime to LocalDate
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(LocalDate localDate) {
            // convert localDate to LocalDateTime
        }
    }
```